# Find all possible combinations that satisfy the condition

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a question about the problem that was given from a TV show[1]

Let set $S = \{(a,b,c)\in Z^+\cup \{0\} |3^a\times5^b+1=2^c\}$
($Z^+$ is a set of positive integers).

What is $\sum_{(a,b,c)\in S} (100a+10b+c)$?

The TV show insists that *all possible* combinations are $(0,0,1), (1,0,2), (1,1,4)$, so the answer is 217 (1 + 102 + 114)

Definitely, it is just an entertainment show; and the proof for the statement "all possible" is not necessary.

However, I am wondering if I can prove(or disprove) that there are only three combinations that satisfy the condition.

Reference

1. 09:34 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3SgI038244